# Reviewing changes in an svn branch

Tags: svn, emacs

We typically developed new features on a separate svn branch.
After finishing the features, another person reviews that branch' changes.

I use emacs with psvn. The svn-status is very convenient.
It marks changed between local (not committed) changes.
It is easy to `ediff` and see all differences from this *svn-status* mode buffer.

Typically I do these step for easing my review of other colleagues work:

```
svn co [svn-branch-url]         # get his branch locally  
cd [check-out-branch]  
svn log -vvv -stop-on-copy      # this gives me all revision involved  
svn diff -r[old]:[latest] >diff.patch # note latest is not HEAD  
svn switch [svn-url]@[old]      # go to the creating of the branch  
patch -p0 diff.patch                 # apply his feature
```

Now emacs allows me with svn-status to see all the changes.
I add some review comments in the source and perform these steps:

```
svn switch [svn-url]@[latest]
```

I now get conflicts. (Again it easy with emacs to review these with `ediff`).
But it is just my review comments.

```
svn resolved [files-in-conflict]  
svn commit -m "review comments"
```

now my colleague can read the comments.

Is there some more practical way of doing this?
How do you this?

Comment: I don't understand why you are switching branches the second time, rather than simply committing your comments to [svn-branch-url]?

Comment: Yes that step might be unnecessary. I'm not 100% comfortable with svn switch. I thought I had to switch back to the last version. Important is that the owner of the change can easily find back review comment tags.

Answer (score 0):

Install Redmine (with the code review plugin) or Reviewboard, it'll show you a big list of all the commit messages and you can do a review of the branch's changes between any 2 revisions. You can also annotate any issues you find and have them automatically be created as tickets for the dev to fix!

Comment: Well, if possible I'd like to stay inside my (emacs) IDE. Also the code base of a project is big and I have to look around using tags to symbols in the complete source tree that the source under review is using. Typically in our process, we commit the review comments as special commented tags in the branch source tree. RB (did not check Redmine yet) would require a change of our process (or working habit. I might have a difficult time to enforce colleagues to change their way of working.

Comment: Its a webapp that also doubles up as a bugtracker and 'project portal' so if you already have those things... RM might be a good replacement. If you don't... RM is a good thing to have anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I see some limitations of your approach:
* You need to pass patch files between people by email;
* You don't leave any trace of the comments given and the discussion made;
* You have a long procedure for the review, which mean people would try to avoid it when they can.

I've been able to use two methods which don't have this limitation:
* Use [malevich](http://malevich.codeplex.com/) or ReviewBoard which create web-sites with the diff in them and allow the reviewers to give the comments there.
* Write a small script (say python code using pysvn) to automate the process, so that developers would just need to write "cr branch-name developer-name" and get the changes open in emacs.